# modeling a 3-way relationshsip

Tags: relational-database, entity-relationship

A has many B, but each B has only one A.
C has many B, but each B has only one C.

A has many C, but each C has only one A.

note that from the first 2 assertions, A and C have a many-to-many relationship. However, from line 3, it is clear that A and C has actually a one-to-many relationship. I need to model a relational database such that each B that C has actually also belongs to the same A that C belongs to.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have just made a big revision to my answer. I don't think you or the selected answerer even know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

- *A* has an arbitrary candidate key, *A_id*
- *C* has a candidate key *(A_id, C_id)* where *C_id* need be unique only wrt *A_id*
- *C* formalizes *C <<--> A* with a foreign key *A_id*
- *B* has a candidate key *(A_id, C_id, B_id)* where *B_id* need be unique only wrt *(A_id, C_id)*
- *B* formalizes *B <<--> A* with a foreign key *A_id*
- *B* formalizes *B <<--> C* with a foreign key *(A_id, C_id)*

Comment: See my answer. I don't think either of you knows what the problem you were supposed to solve was.

Comment: I looked at your answer. It is good, but it doesnt answer what I asked. this one is precisely what I need. The whole problem would be clearer if I used real wolrd examples, but I am pretty sure aztecrex got it right.

Comment: @TapiocaCom Both you & he confuse tables, foreign keys and entities. If I get a chance I'll address that in my answer. But good luck.

Comment: a table, or relation, is a set of tuples having the same attributes. Foreign key is a kind of integrity constraint that is used to force a group of attributes to have a value that matches similar attributes declared as primary keys on another table. Entity is an abstract concept that can be modeled by 1 or more tables and integrity constraints. In my question, I was speaking abstractly, therefore I was talking about entities. When I say: A has many B, it can be understood that the entity A may be associated with 0, 1, 2, ... instances of the entity B. But this is not mathematical formalism...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT big revision plus keys

When you see "a" "X-to-Y" "relationship", ask, "*which* relationship?". "X-to-Y" is a property of some particular relationship. *Which one?*

"Relationship" gets used two ways. Sometimes it means *relation*. (As embodied by a table. The table contains the rows satisfying some associated statement parameterized by the table columns). As in the relational model and ERM. Sometimes its means "foreign key". ORMs are confused about this. Often ERM is presented with confusions about this. You are using "has-a" along these muddled lines.

You can't determine keys, fks or constraints (which subsume arity) without knowing what the relationships the tables embody are!

Your use of "has-a" is unclear so I'm just going to guess at (some of) the relationships you are talking about.

```
is_an_A(a)
    -- a identifies an A-thing
    -- key a
is_a_B(b)
    -- b identifies a B-thing
    -- key b
is_a_C(c)
    -- c identifies a C-thing
    -- key c
blah_blah_about_an_A_and_a_B(a,b)
    -- is_an_A(a) AND is_a_B(b) AND ...a...b...
    -- key b
    -- fk a to is_a_A, fk b to is_a_B
    -- a:b 1:many
something_about_a_B_and_a_C(b,c)
    -- is_an_B(b) AND is_a_C(c) AND ...b...c...
    -- key b
    -- fk b to is_a_B, fk c to is_a_C
    -- b:c many:1
```

You don't seem to have the is_as in your database. But we can reason with them.

Now the relationship you first mention seems to be this one that can be expressed by the others:

```
first(a,c) ==
EXISTS b such that
    blah_blah_about_an_A_and_B(a,b)
AND something_about_a_B_and_a_C(b,c)
-- key c
-- fk a to is_an_A, fk c to is_a_C
-- a:c is 1:many
```

Because of the arities of its constituent relationships this *might* be many-to-many but we don't know if it's really more constrained than that without knowing the actual relationships and what situations can arise. But it seems like you're still talking about this relationship when you say "A and C has actually a one-to-many relationship". This relationshop is embodied by this table:

```
SELECT a,c
FROM blah_blah_about_an_A_and_B
NATURAL JOIN something_about_a_B_and_a_C
```

But there could be other relationships.

You are using "belongs to" ambiguously for both of my "about" relationships above, or maybe the relationships that put the things in the other direction.

```
related_in_reverse_B_A(b,a) -- blah_blah_about_an_A_and_B(b,a)
```

Again, when you see "a" "belongs-to" "relationship" or "a" "is-a" "relationship" the belongs-to and is-a are properties of some relationships. *Which ones?*

You seem to be interested in a certain other relationship that can also be expressed by the above. But you are not even clear about what parameters that relationship is even on. I think you mean this one:

```
second(b,c) ==
EXITS a such that
    blah_blah_about_an_A_and_B(a,b)
AND something_about_a_B_and_a_C(b,c)
AND first(a,c)
-- key c
-- fk b to is_a_B, fk c to is_a_C
-- b:c is 1:many
```

The key is c is because a:c is 1:many per first and b:c is 1:many oer something_about_a_B_and_a_C. This is embodied by the table

```
SELECT *
FROM blah_blah_about_an_A_and_B
NATURAL JOIN something_about_a_B_and_a_C
NATURAL JOIN first
```

Because first and second are expressible by the others, if in the database they would not be base but views. But I suspect you were actually told they were exprssible and are meant to be queries.

Your message is unclear, as you can see by my guessing. Please clarify it.

Strongly suggest you also make sure you know how to rephrase your entire message clearly along these lines. And always force yourself to think in these terms.